# call to undefined fucntion error

Tags: chaos-tool-suite

Call to undefined function modalframe_close_dialog() in

I am using Drupal 7

```
function close_model_dialog($form, &$form_state) {
  ctools_include('ajax');
  ctools_include('modal');
  ctools_modal_add_js();
  $form_state['redirect'] = FALSE;
  modalframe_close_dialog();
  modalframe_child_js();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means what it says: There is no file included in the current page request that contains the definition for a function called `modalframe_close_dialog()`.

A quick Google search shows that this function is part of the [`ModalFrame API`](http://drupal.org/project/modalframe) module, for which there is only a Drupal 6 release (not Drupal 7). I guess you've copied this code from a Drupal 6 site without changing it?

The comments on the ModalFrame API module page say:

> It seems this feature is being included in Drupal core itself. So, probably there will be no stable release of this module for Drupal 7 because it will be already there

My best guess is that the Drupal 7 equivalent of this function is [`overlay_close_dialog()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!overlay!overlay.module/function/overlay_close_dialog/7), but I can't comment as to whether that will work as in a drop-in replacement for you current code.

It might be worth reading the [Initial D7UX admin overlay](http://drupal.org/node/517688) thread, it's basically the discussion about moving ModalFrame API into core.

Comment: Thanks CLive I have replaced function with $output[] = ctools_modal_command_dismiss(); print ajax_render($output); exit; and it works fine but the issue is if I use paging on model and close from page other than page 1 it reloads the parent giving some junk output